# FileNotFound Exception while sending SMS through way2sms webservice

Tags: java, way2sms

I am using AswinAnand Free SMS Web service. While running below code, I am getting below exception. Please direct me to the right way.

```
try 
        {
            SMS.send("9884840204", "*****", "9884840204", "Hello Java World");
        }
```

**Exception:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://wwwd.way2sms.com/auth.cl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1234)
    at com.aswinanand.sms.SMS.send(SMS.java:75)
    at com.wipro.common.SendSMS.main(SendSMS.java:13)
```

Comment: Sounds like a technical support question to me...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of `SMS.java`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
```

is requesting the input stream of the [www.way2sms.com](http://www.way2sms.com) URL. So it seams that your authentication with www.way2sms.com fails.
If you have an account at www.way2sms.com and this still happens it's obviously a bug.

Comment: I have way2sms account. Still i got this exception. So how should i resolve this issue?

Comment: I would report it to Aswin Anand at [free-sms-web-service](http://www.aswinanand.com/2009/01/free-sms-web-service-java-library/) directly.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know once you get any response from him.

Comment: It was rather meant as a suggestion to you, that if I were you I would report it to Aswin Anand.

Comment: i am getting the same error if you get the solution to this problem please let me know.